# Dispatcher between classes

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, dispatcher

Learning C#, WPF. Currently trying to get to grips with Dispatchers, specifically between threads and other classes.

I got my dispatcher to work when in the 'MainWindow' class, but when I separate it out as below into another class I get the compile error message "The type 'System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher' has no constructors defined"

Clearly a basic learning error, but I can't figure it out. Code below, a push in the right direction please :)

```
namespace threading_dispatcher_learn
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {

        public delegate void MyDel();

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            label1.Content = "Label1";

            this.label2.Content = this.Dispatcher.Thread.ManagedThreadId;


            Myupdator updateclass = new Myupdator();


            Thread MyNewThread;


            MyNewThread = new Thread(updateclass.UpdateLabel);
            MyNewThread.Start();


        }



        private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Clicked");
        }

    }

    public class Myupdator
    {

        public void UpdateLabel()
        {
            MainWindow.MyDel del1 = delegate()
            {

                try
                {
                   // label1.Content = "Update 2";
                    //Thread.Sleep(3000);
                    MessageBox.Show("Message 2");
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
                }
            };

           /* Now removed
             Dispatcher myDispather = new Dispatcher();
            myDispather.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, del1);
*/
        //now added
        Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, del1);
        Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.InvokeShutdown();

        }
    }

}
```

**UPDATE**: Code modified above, is this the correct way? Am I understanding you correctly? Although nothing in 'del1' is getting called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not supposed to create a `Dispatcher` instane using a constructor. To access the `Dispatcher` for the current thread (or create a new one if one does not already exist) simply get the value of [`Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.currentdispatcher.aspx). Do not forget to shut down the dispatcher (e.g. with [`Dispatcher.InvokeShutdown`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.invokeshutdown.aspx)) when it's no longer needed.

However, why are you doing this? In the overwhelming majority of cases, creating a `Dispatcher` is the wrong thing to do. `Dispatcher` models a Windows message loop, so it's only meaningful on UI threads.

**Update:** It seems that you are simply trying to modify the contents of the label and show a dialog box. **You must not create a new `Dispatcher` for this**; instead, use the `Dispatcher` already created on your UI thread. You need to pass to your new thread the value of `Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher` *as taken from your main thread*, or alternatively you need to pass a reference to any UI control (e.g. a label, or the window itself).

For example:

```
var mainWindow = ... ; // you need to pass this to your new thread somehow
mainWindow.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, del1);
```

Let me repeat the rule of thumb once again: *unless you have extensive experience in multithreaded applications, creating a new `Dispatcher` is always the wrong thing to do*.

Comment: Now using "            Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, del1);
            Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.InvokeShutdown();" which has removed the error, but the actions within the thread are not taking place. I do want to perform an action on the GUI, it's just commented out at the moment and replaced with a messagebox.

Comment: @Damo: No. Simply forget about creating a new dispatcher! Inside the constructor of `MainWindow`, keep a reference to `this` and pass that to your new thread; that's the `mainWindow` in my updated example.